# Global Scope and module scope difference in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

Despite a topic with loads of resource, i still can't fully understand the difference between global scope and module scope in the React context. Hoping someone can shed a light on how to understand the concept of `scope` (or perhaps I should mix the concept with React?).

According to [scope docs from mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope), `x` is in global scope.

```js
const x = "declared outside function"; // x is in global scope

exampleFunction();

function exampleFunction() {
  console.log("Inside function");
  console.log(x);
}

console.log("Outside function");
console.log(x);
```

But apparently, below code won't work in React, which according to [mdn doc of var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), variable declared with `var` outside a function is globally-scoped.

```js
// a.js
var x = "declared outside function";

export function exampleFunction() {
  console.log("Inside function");
  console.log(x);
}


// b.js
import {exampleFunction} from './a.js'
console.log(x); // x is not defined
```

If I haven't misunderstood the definition of module, every .js file in React is considered a module?

Given this context and my understanding, is `x` variable still considered globally-scoped, or it should be considered belonging to `a.js`'s module scope?

What about `exampleFunction`? Is it still considered module-scoped even though it's being exported?

What are the practices to declare variables that are **truly globally-scoped**? What comes to mind is adding it to `window` object, declaring it inside html file with a `<script>` tag, adding it in a `.env` file.

Correction on my understanding or pointing to a solid resource is appreciated.

Comment: Top-level declarations in modules are **not** global.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the reply! but if since ES6 every .js file is considered a module, can i infer  that only variables declared in `<script>` tag , `window` object and `.env` file considered globally-scoped (perhaps other methods exist that i've missed)? while variables declared in `<script type='module'> `  or exported function or variables aren't cause they are module-scoped?

Comment: And the variable `x` in the first code snippet is only considered globally-scoped when i execute  the code directly in a runtime such as  the browser console?

Comment: Well that's per the spec; in reality, in a browser only a module imported with `type=module` in the `<script>` tag are modules. In Node, whether a source file is a module or not depends on the `package.json` setting, also whether the extension of a source file is `.mjs` (for a module).

Comment: In addition, module or not, `const` and `let` variables are not exported to the global scope implicitly.